# OpenCL version missing from User Prefs

Tags: rendering, gpu, opencl, system

[image]

As seen in the picture, I have no option to select OpenCL as a solution to render with. I'm using Blender 2.78.5 (the version where we do have the Principled BSDF shader). 
I'm on AMD Radeon HD 8730M which is supposed to be supported, and I did check it using the `set CYCLES_OPENCL_TEST=ALL` environment variable. 
I have the latest AMD driver installed, 17.6.2, with the OpenCL™ Version
22.19.171.257. 
I'm using Windows 10 64 bit. 
I'd like someone skilled to tell me how to get GPU rendering up and running.

Comment: Just to point out, Principled BSDF shader is in 2.79 (top bar shows 2.78.5).

Comment: True, I edit the version number to 2.78.5, Thanks.